# Rails - @mentions using at.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to implement @mentions for my application using the At.js library from

https://github.com/ichord/At.js

I'm having some issues triggering the at functionality (triggered by the callback in the code below). I have setup the following coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $("textarea").atWho "@", (query, callback) ->
    console.log("@who") 
    $.ajax 
      url: "/users/mentions.json"
      param: q: query 
      done: (data) ->
        console.log("in callback")
        console.log(data)
        names = $.parseJSON(data)
        console.log(names)
        callback names
```

From the js and rails consoles I can see that the controller action is getting called, however no other calls are made.

This library has been working fine for me with static data so I think that the callback syntax is an issue. Does anyone have any pointers for this?

EDIT:

I've adapted Nick's solution below and changed to use a get request and this works fine for querying and returning data from the rails app using the following revised code:

```
$ ->
  $("textarea").atWho "@", (query, callback) ->
    console.log("@who") 
    $.get "/users/mentions.json", q: query, ((result) ->
      console.log("in callback")
      console.log("result: ")
      console.log(result)
      names = $.parseJSON(result)
      console.log(names)
      callback names
    ), "json"
```

However there is still a problem with the parseJSON(result) line - it returns null every time.
I have tried changing the json which I am sending to the very simple {"name":"james"} and it is still not returning anything - can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the line `param: q: data` to `data: q: data`. The [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function doesn't support passing a `param` option.

Comment: Thanks Nick - this seems to have worked for that problem. I have another problem, I've edited the question above to show.. any more advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to parse the JSON at all. Your ajax call does that already. Try `names = result` instead of `names = $.parseJSON(result)`

Comment: With the above suggestion I get an error Object #<Object> has no method 'splice'